# php unset foreach loop is not unsetting the value of array

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I have the following code in php 7.2:

```
foreach ($data->certificates as $k => $certificate) {
    if (empty($certificate['testCertificateId'])) {
        unset($data->certificates[$k]);
    }
}
```

`$data` is an associative array. Each `$certificate` is an associative array.

If a `$certificate` array has no key `testCertificateId`, I want to remove the `$certificate` from `$data->certificates`.

I have no clue why, but this code doesn't work on php 7.2. On 7.0 it does work!

Could anyone please help? It's killing me for 2 days already...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: You say '$data is an associative array', but you're using it as an object. What kind of object is it?

Comment: @EvE, god damn it, you are 100% right. it is the Zend Framework's object `Zend\Stdlib\Parameters`, I'll dig it further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround for your current code:

```
$tempArr = [];
foreach ($data->certificates as $k => $certificate) {
    if (!empty($certificate['testCertificateId'])) {
        $tempArr[$k] = $data->certificates[$k];
    }
}
$data->certificates = $tempArr;
```

Comment: i'll mark your answer as correct because it is not application-specific. it turned out mine was application-specific: `$data` variable was an instance of a class of Zend Framework, not a regular array.